# OsmAnd: How to hide information?

Tags: osmand

OsmAnd has so much information that it obscures the map. How can I decide what information (layers) that OsmAnd should show?

I had hoped Define View > POI would make it possible to hide the information, but it can only emphasize the information with an orange circle.

[image: OsmAnd has too much information]

Answer (score 0):

I use OsmAnd+ 2.3.5 and that was the first thought I had - too much of everything. It is all configurable, though.

```
tap the menu button -> Configure Map -> swipe up to reveal more options
```

See pictures below, I highlighted the options of your interest. You can disable the POIs (the orange circles you mentioned) and you can further hide things such as buildings and lots of other miscellaneous details.

[image: Main menu]
[image: Configure map menu]
[image: Configure map menu further down]

By disabling what I mentioned above here is what you can achieve (you can go even further and hide polygons too (grass, water, etc.)).

[image: Most details]
[image: No POIs]
[image: A lot of stuff hidden from view]